# Which particular file caused "Delayed write failed" error?

Tags: windows-xp, external-hard-drive, ntfs, hibernate

I sometimes get this error when resuming from hibernation:

```
Delayed Write Failed: 
Windows was unable to save all the data for the file G:\$Mft. 
The data  has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of
your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save 
this file elsewhere.
```

I know this is caused because the hard drive (G:, an external USB drive) was (a) plugged in when I hibernated and wasn't ready at wake-up, or (b) I simply forgot to plug it when resuming from hibernation.

My question is: ***is there any way to see which particular file/folder/etc failed to be written***? The hard drive functions correctly before and after, so there seems to be no permanent damage.

Is there a detailed log someplace or a utility?  I've searched but found nothing.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT : If no such utility is found - is there a way to tell windows : *"wait  - check again - the drive you think was missing is back"*.

Answer (score 4):

[$MFT](http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/file/ntfs/archMFT-c.html) (Master File Table) is the name of the file itself. It stores the main copy of the filesystem table on NTFS filesystems.

Your problem is probably caused by the fact that the USB hardware is turned of at hibernation time and turned on too late in the resume. One possible solution is to check you motherboard for jumpers that allow you to switch USB power from +5V to +5VSB (this meaning the USB will always remain powered on when you turn off your computer from inside the operating system). 
The downside of this is that your device may also be left always on.

Another solution would be to simply unplug (or turn off) the external hard disk before hibernating (not the best option, I know, but at least you'll not get the error any longer)

Comment: Thanks - I know - so there is *no* utility that can produce a more verbose log ? I am not looking for solutions as  : a) I might be unable to unplug legally (solution 2 is out), and just pulling it out might as well result in the same error (and no warning) and b) not sure solution 1 works (USB powers up when I plug it and resume from hibernation/standby but windows do not read it in time).
So I was looking for some app that says : failed to add file X to $mft - or for a log by windows someplace.